# Can Rbuilder print without preview?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2

I use RBuilder to print barcode in my application. When I use `ppreport1.print` it shows a print preview but this requires to press *Print* button again for print.

How can I print without preview ?

Comment: Does [this](https://forums.embarcadero.com/thread.jspa?threadID=81375) help?